# Assign value to Swift property

Tags: ios, variables, swift, properties

When should I assign value to properties in swift?

What is the difference between

```
class Thing {
    var something:String = "Cool Thing"
}
```

and this

```
class Thing {
    var something:String
    init(){
        something = "Cool Thing"
    }
}
```

Actually its quite obvious when value is assigned on init() but when is value assigned when using 1st piece of code and which is the right way to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're the same, but Apple suggests using the default property value pattern "if a property always takes the same initial value" for stylistic reasons. See the note in *Default Property Values* section of [The Swift Programming Language: Initialization](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html), which says:

> #### Default Property Values
>
> You can set the initial value of a stored property from within an initializer, as shown above. Alternatively, specify a default property value as part of the property’s declaration. You specify a default property value by assigning an initial value to the property when it is defined.
>
> > NOTE: If a property always takes the same initial value, provide a default value rather than setting a value within an initializer. The end result is the same, but the default value ties the property’s initialization more closely to its declaration. It makes for shorter, clearer initializers and enables you to infer the type of the property from its default value. The default value also makes it easier for you to take advantage of default initializers and initializer inheritance, as described later in this chapter.

Comment: Note: you won't be able to use this initializer in Obj-C

Comment: What initializer do you mean? If you have properties in Swift class with default values, those values will be initialized regardless of whatever initializer you call from Objective-C.

Comment: I was wrong, because: 1. I mixed "Default Property Values" and "Default Parameter Values" in `init` method. 2. Init with default parameter values works in Obj-C, but didn't work for me in one specific case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of the 2. The difference is that if you have multiple initializer you might need to replicate the property initialization. Besides that it's just a matter of preference.

Comment: Just curiosity: even in a case where multiple initializers are needed, we would not need to replicate the property init due to the fact that we use the designated initializer pattern, right?

Comment: You can have more than one designated initializer - and ofc you cannot call one from another, nor use a common initialization func. In that case the only option is to replicate the props initialization, or use inline initialization

Answer (score 0):

They should both be doing the same thing. The main difference for not initializing first would be if you wanted to assign the var as an optional and test for nil. Otherwise assigning the value would be the same.

```
var something:String?
```